# Applying element wise operation on a 2D matrix using summarized column information in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 2D matrix and I want to access every element in a vectorized operation.
The operation I'd like to perform it is easy: take the value in the cell and add the min between all the values in the same column (or row). In other words, I want to apply a offset on every cell of the value that depend on all the values of the columns (or row) where the cell belongs to.

How can I do it? There is a easy way? I don't want to use loops or auxiliaries vectors.

Example

```
my.data <- matrix( seq(1:30) , nrow = 3 )
my.data
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25    28
[2,]    2    5    8   11   14   17   20   23   26    29
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27    30
```

e.g. I want the column 2 to be c(8,9,10) and so on.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
my.data.mod <- apply(my.data, 2, function(x) x+min(x))
my.data.mod

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    2    8   14   20   26   32   38   44   50    56
[2,]    3    9   15   21   27   33   39   45   51    57
[3,]    4   10   16   22   28   34   40   46   52    58
```

If you want to do it by row:

```
my.data.mod <- t(apply(my.data, 1, function(x) x+min(x)))
my.data.mod

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    2    5    8   11   14   17   20   23   26    29
[2,]    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25   28    31
[3,]    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30    33
```

Comment: `apply` is a loop though (upvoted for understanding the question)

Comment: @thepule, I didn't believe that can be so easy, but when I do like `apply( my.data , 2 , function(x) x+1-min(x) )` it is not working.

Comment: @HubertL, I should have been more explicit: I meant custom loop like `for`.

Comment: @thepule, I am not an R expert and I don't know the innermost mechanisms and the S3/4 language itself, but what I found weird is that your beautiful and easy solution is working. How can R distinguish between the `x` as one dimensional variable and the `x` as vector in the same context without any other specifier?

Comment: The way I interpret it (not necessarily correctly) is that x represent the column vector. Therefore `min(x)` is the minimum for that vector. So when adding `x + min(x)` it's like adding a number to a vector which in R is a vectorized operation. Same as `c(1,2,3) + min(c(1,2,3))`. That's why I am a bit confused as to why it doesn't work subtracting the minimum...

Comment: @alevax OK I think we have been silly. The code it's actually working I think. `apply( my.data , 2 , function(x) x+1-min(x) )` correctly produces a data frame where all the columns are 1,2,3. Do you get a different result?

Comment: @thepule, right now! You are completely right. My dataset in the example was silly and I didn't expected the result. I should have used a random dataset. Thank you very much for the answer, it is working.

Comment: @thepule, please tell me if I understood it right. When I use x as vector as the `apply` parameter, the summarized operation (e.g. min()) is applied to all the x vector and the `min(x)` is coerced to a vector of length(x) with all the elements having value min(x).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115352/discussion-between-thepule-and-alevax).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach built around [`pmin()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extremes.html).

By row:

```
my.data+do.call(pmin,as.data.frame(my.data));
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## [1,]    2    5    8   11   14   17   20   23   26    29
## [2,]    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25   28    31
## [3,]    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30    33
```

By column:

```
t(t(my.data)+do.call(pmin,as.data.frame(t(my.data))));
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## [1,]    2    8   14   20   26   32   38   44   50    56
## [2,]    3    9   15   21   27   33   39   45   51    57
## [3,]    4   10   16   22   28   34   40   46   52    58
```

---

## Benchmarking

```
library(microbenchmark);

thepule.col <- function(m) apply(m,2L,function(x) x+min(x));
thepule.row <- function(m) t(apply(m,1L,function(x) x+min(x)));
bgoldst.col <- function(m) t(t(m)+do.call(pmin,as.data.frame(t(m))));
bgoldst.row <- function(m) m+do.call(pmin,as.data.frame(m));
```

---

```
## small scale (OP's example)
NR <- 3L; NC <- 10L; m <- matrix(seq_len(NR*NC),NR);

ex.col <- thepule.col(m);
identical(ex.col,bgoldst.col(m));
## [1] TRUE
ex.row <- thepule.row(m);
identical(ex.row,bgoldst.row(m));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(thepule.col(m),bgoldst.col(m));
## Unit: microseconds
##            expr    min     lq     mean  median     uq     max neval
##  thepule.col(m) 36.351 40.200 46.30256 42.5520 50.891 107.769   100
##  bgoldst.col(m) 38.489 41.055 47.26482 42.9795 52.602 105.631   100
microbenchmark(thepule.row(m),bgoldst.row(m));
## Unit: microseconds
##            expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
##  thepule.row(m) 31.647 33.358 36.83026 35.0685 36.5655 103.920   100
##  bgoldst.row(m) 44.477 47.043 51.16077 48.5395 50.6775 133.856   100
```

---

```
## medium scale
NR <- 1e2L; NC <- 1e3L; m <- matrix(seq_len(NR*NC),NR);

ex.col <- thepule.col(m);
identical(ex.col,bgoldst.col(m));
## [1] TRUE
ex.row <- thepule.row(m);
identical(ex.row,bgoldst.row(m));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(thepule.col(m),bgoldst.col(m));
## Unit: milliseconds
##            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##  thepule.col(m) 3.088080 3.193068 5.032765 4.344523 4.655640 38.55630   100
##  bgoldst.col(m) 1.692221 1.829712 3.128527 2.095925 3.117374 36.80976   100
microbenchmark(thepule.row(m),bgoldst.row(m));
## Unit: milliseconds
##            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##  thepule.row(m) 1.779035 2.108755 4.472138 3.378242 3.708603 39.84353   100
##  bgoldst.row(m) 3.674818 3.942316 4.862983 4.173248 5.219714 40.63212   100
```

---

```
## large scale
NR <- 1e3L; NC <- 1e4L; m <- matrix(seq_len(NR*NC),NR);

ex.col <- thepule.col(m);
identical(ex.col,bgoldst.col(m));
## [1] TRUE
ex.row <- thepule.row(m);
identical(ex.row,bgoldst.row(m));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(thepule.col(m),bgoldst.col(m));
## Unit: milliseconds
##            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##  thepule.col(m) 194.4044 238.1129 244.0346 243.1782 248.4054 306.6919   100
##  bgoldst.col(m) 340.0291 382.0265 388.2586 387.3593 395.8638 463.1242   100
microbenchmark(thepule.row(m),bgoldst.row(m));
## Unit: milliseconds
##            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##  thepule.row(m) 259.3259 282.6383 304.7577 294.8812 329.2672 376.1987   100
##  bgoldst.row(m) 142.1778 153.2129 167.5441 157.6520 169.3705 217.0170   100
```